# DB Trigger Compatible with Both Oracle and HSQLDB

Tags: oracle, syntax, compatibility, hsqldb, database-trigger

I am writing integration tests that use HSQLDB, while in production the application makes use of an Oracle DB. On Oracle I have a trigger that if the primary key of a particular table is empty then it is populated using the next value from a sequence. I need this trigger to work in HSQLDB but I can seem to find a way to make the script work for both DBs; Below is the trigger as generated by Oracle SQL Dev Studio:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "WFMEXTENSIONS"."WORK_TRG" 
BEFORE INSERT ON WORK 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.WORK_ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT WORK_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.WORK_ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
/
```

HSQL DB is being run in "Oracle Compatibility Mode" using

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;
```

Any ideas how the trigger can be modified to work on both DBs?

Comment: Why don't you use an identity column in both DBMS and get rid of the trigger completely?

Comment: In oracle the identity column was added in v12 and I am using v11 (and it is not within my control to upgrade)

Comment: Then use an identity column in HSQLDB and forget the trigger there. The "behaviour" will be identical

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice on the [HSQL trigger syntax](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/triggers-chapt.html#trc_row_references) is that their row references (old and new) don't get prefixed with the colon as Oracle does. I don't have access to an HSQL DB to test out items like if it will accept " REFERENCING NEW AS :new", but that wouldn't be compatible with Oracle anyway, so is of no help.

Similarly, the default sequence access also seems different:

```
INSERT INTO childtable VALUES 4, CURRENT VALUE FOR mysequence
```

So the question is just how compatible the Oracle compatibility mode is. Does it mean compatibility in stored code syntax? Or just compatibility for statements? [The guide does not give me optimism:](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/compatibility-chapt.html#coc_compatibility_oracle)

> SQL routines are generally portable, but some changes are required.

Not "may be required". "Are required". Frankly, I think you may be trying something that isn't likely to end in success.

Answer (score 0):

It will look like this in HSQLDB

```
CREATE TRIGGER "WFMEXTENSIONS"."WORK_TRG" 
BEFORE INSERT ON WORK REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN ATOMIC
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    IF NEW.WORK_ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT WORK_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO NEW.WORK_ID FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
  END;
END
```

The stored procedure syntax is somewhat different from Oracle but the individual SQL statements can use the supported Oracle syntax such as `NEXTVAL` and `DUAL`

Comment: I tried running this code and it returns the following error `CREATE TRIGGER WORK_TRG BEFORE INSERT ON WORK REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NEW FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ATOMIC BEGIN ATOMIC IF NEW.WORK_ID IS NULL THEN SELECT WORK_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO NEW.WORK_ID FROM DUAL; unexpected end of statement:  required: ;` any ideas please?

Comment: It is the program you are using to enter the script. It needs to accept semicolons and not terminate reading when there is one.